# Get the substring From the Html file without considering the tags only text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to `WebDevelopment`. I have a html document consider it as  a resume,and that is in the html format. e.g -
**html**

```
<p>Mobile: 12345678891
E-mail: <a href="abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a></p>
<p><b>Career Objective</b></p>
<p>Employment that fully utilizes my experience in Web Site Design &amp; Development and offers the opportunity for career advancement along with the further expansion of IT skills.
</p><p><b>Career Summary
</b></p><p><b>2.1 years</b> of experience in analysis, design and development of client/server, web based application.
```

Now, In this Now I want to have a substring from this html string. I want to have 
**my experience in Web Site** this string. Now, I tried to take this string from `subString` method, I get the `start and end offset`so, Here, What happens when I took `innerText`,it does not matches. So How to get the substring which I am displaying in that way only? And If I want to give the the id to the each and every word which is present in html including special char and space as well then How can do this ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Specify your intended final outcome clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't assign an ID to anything that is not a HTML tag. So individual words or characters cannot have an ID.

Second, try with `innerHTML` property, that contains exact content. `innerText` contains only text, so indices can change.